# If I play a custom map in warcraft 3 online (such as dota), will I get a copy of that map?

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

I believe that's the way it used to work. I can't seem to find a safe-looking site to download the map from. It would also appear that the official forums were taken down some time ago. Its been years and years since I last played online (as in around 10 years ago), and I believe that if you played a custom map online, the game would save that map in your game for you to either play offline or host yourself. But I'm not sure that's 100% accurate, and besides blizzard appears to have started updating the game again, so its possible they may have changed that.

The reason I want to know this is so I can look up the items in dota 1. I can only find information online for dota 2, which isn't identical to dota 1. If I could get a map through the game that I can play offline, I could just open up the game offline and look at everything that way. As for playing that match, I was planning on playing a support so I could get away with not having to buy too many items. I don't want to sabotage everyone else's game to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Before playing any map in warcraft 3, you will be in some kind of lobby.
In that lobby every player has the (automatic) ability to download the map from the host (lobby creator).
The download progress is indicated by a number in front of the player name counting up from 0 to 100 (%).

Every player needs to download the map for the host to be able to start the game. Once the map is downloaded, it will be located in your local game folder under custom maps (or something similar).

It is worth noting that many hosts are not happy with players downloading a commonly used map before the game, because it takes time, so it might not be easy to make the download. This might no longer be the case, but it used to be that way.

There are also some external lobbies such as garena, dotalicious, etc. Which sometimes modify the lobby in a way that changes from the original. My explanation above regards to the "normal" lobby that is included in warcraft 3 without modifications.

Comment: I do seem to recall having issue with people kicking me out of games for not having the map. Hopefully, that's no longer an issue with modern internet speeds. Though its possible they may assume I'm a noob because of that and kick me out just to prevent risking having me feed. I do recall the community long ago was quite hostile to new comers (everyone seemed to think that you had no right to play a game if you had never played that map before). Of course, people ARE going to have to download the latest version every time a new one comes out (assuming dota 1 is even being updated anymore).

Comment: Whilst I haven't used BattleNet (online Warcraft III) for many years, I recall that I was kicked out of Dota matches every time when I hadn't predownloaded the map (yes, every time). I believed that kicking people without the map out of games wasn't just an issue of taking time to download the map, but that not having the map suggested you haven't played the game before and were thus likely to be bad at that game. They rather kick you out and wait for someone more likely to be good at the game.

Comment: I remember back when Eul was making DotA maps, long before DotA Allstars came along. I had fast for the time (300 KB/s) upload on my unlimited cable line, so I'd just leave lobbies running overnight whenever he released a new version to let everyone download fast. Sucked when I'd get randomly disconnected sometimes.